# Add php nature to project

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have a question about PHP projects in eclipse.
I have Aptana and PDT installed in my eclipse.
When I create PHP Project, I have something like this:

[image: 2.png]

But if I add PHP nature to the project (org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature) then I get following picture:

[image: 1.png]

Is this normal at all? What are the benefits of this PHP nature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely normal and part of how PDT provides Code Assist in PHP projects.

Basically PHP Language Library contains what you can find in the PHP documentation. When you call a core function e.g. `preg_replace()` it will provide Code Assist, like autocompletion and showing you which arguments the function takes. It's just a  bunch of Interfaces for core features, SPL containing phpdoc generated from the documentation.

The PHP Include Path resembles your `include_path` in PHP, in that you can refer to stuff outside your project, e.g. PEAR or a common folder containing shared PHP classes, which are then recognized by Eclipe's Code Assist.

is just a hierarchy view of your global namespace, similar to how you can unfold a php file and see its hierarchy directly from the explorer.

Comment: How Can I watch my classes under global node? Or moreover with similiar structure like on pic1?

Comment: Just unfold it, to see the details by clicking on the arrow (see: http://imgur.com/s02Nq.png). I am not sure if you can double click on global to jump to where it is defined.

Comment: I'v got one more question. Is there any option to create source folders, like onn your screenshot? Because it seems that I can't do it or doing something wrong.

Comment: This is handled in the Build Path-settings. When you're importing an existing project, PDT detects folders as source folder, if they contain php files. Unfortunately this can mess up the Build Path, as each source folder is added separately. This is problematic, as new folders are not considered to be in the Build Path by default, i.e. you have to add them manually. I usually set up my project to use the the project directory as build path and then add non-source folders to the ignore list, e.g. docs/, data/, tmp/. This way each new folder is automatically considered a source folder.